# Using Conditional Operator for If..Else

Tags: java, talend

I am trying to modify an existing expression in Talend Open Studio using the IF..ELSE logic with a conditional operator.

The logic is:

```
    IF (row73.Month01 == NULL || row73.Month01 == 0.0) THEN 1
    ELSE
    { 
        IF (row46.month01 == NULL || row46.Month01 == 0.0) THEN 1
        ELSE (row46.Month01*100.0f/row73.Month01)
    }
```

The expression with the conditional operator I am entering is:

```
    (row73.Month01==null||row73.Month01==0.0)?1: (row46.Month01==null||row46.Month01==0.0)?1: (row46.Month01*100.0f/row73.Month01))
```

However, when Testing the expression in Talend, it said "Unresolved compilaton".  I tried to test the above in a standalone java skeleton file, but then I am getting the "source_file.java:13: error: on "?"

What am I doing wrong in the above expression format for Talend?

Greatly appreciate any input.

TIA,
Bee

---

Realised one more thing. The datatype for Month01 is defined as Float in the workflow. Given that, is the Null check even valid at all? Since this is a primitive data type and not an object. Shouldnt just the check for row73.Month01 == 0.0 suffice?

Currently, this job is failing on a Null Pointer exception since Month01 has null values in the input source. Hence trying to handle it.

Thanks again.

Comment: Currently your brackets are mismatched in the Java code... not sure what that has to do with the Talend code, but it may be relevant.

Comment: Braces are missing...:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a syntax error in

```
(row73.Month01==null||row73.Month01==0.0)?1: 
(row46.Month01==null||row46.Month01==0.0)?1: 
(row46.Month01*100.0f/row73.Month01))
```

You need an opening parenthesis in the second line:

```
(row73.Month01==null||row73.Month01==0.0)?1: 
((row46.Month01==null||row46.Month01==0.0)?1: 
(row46.Month01*100.0f/row73.Month01))
```

Comment: aah..thank you. After I posted that, I realised one more thing. The datatype for Month01 is float. Given that, is the Null check even valid at all?  Instead, should I be only checking for: IF Month01 = 0.0? Currently, this job is failing on a null pointer exception in this mapping. Trying to do some cleanup here..

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error is just an extra parenthesis in last line and wrong value **100.0f** while multiplying with double value and also **1** instead of 1.0

Correct syntax will be as below:

```
    (row73.Month01==null||row73.Month01==0.0)?1.0: 
    (row46.Month01==null||row46.Month01==0.0)?1.0:
    (row46.Month01*100.0/row73.Month01)
```

However when there is null values in source for any of Month value where you are not using **== null** job will be failed with null pointer exception error. For your syntax now you will not get any error by using above syntax, just to make sure you are using double data type.

For better practice always use not null condition while using tmap.